# Bash script sshd group check

Tags: bash

hello I have script written in python. This script is saving results output of bash script modules. I have to written module that check that are user in 
cat /etc/group |grep sshd and write in excel
in group 203. When i execute command command in host i recveive output

```
staff:!:,sshd,sosnix,xo29321,siwja8211,293912,29314
sshd:!:203:sshd
```

In this module "compilant" and "actual_value" this is row's from excel

My code of module

```
    module_id="XX.TEST"
echo " === $module_id module === "

command_output=`cat /etc/group |grep sshd`

if [ "$command_output" = "cat /etc/group |grep sshd" ]; then
    compliant="Yes"
    actual_value="GUID 203"
else
    compliant="No"
    actual_value="N/A"
fi

# SCRIPT RESULT
echo :::$module_id:::$compliant:::$actual_value:::
echo " === End of $module_id module === "
```

and this script write in my excel result No In compilant and N/A in actual value

Answer (score 0):

This is correct behavior.

You compare two strings: first string with result of cat /etc/group |grep sshd execution and second string the command itself - "cat /etc/group |grep sshd".

These strings are not equivalent. So 'If' goes by 'else' branch and you got the mentioned output.

Please refer for https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html  "6.4 Bash Conditional Expressions" for more information.